# How to Know who creates (host name) a database in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, hostname

I want to know who created a database in sql server. Not the owner user, but the HOST_NAME or the machine name of the user who creates the database. Someone created a database on the server, but we do not know who it was. The only data we have is the user owner of the database, but that user is used by any developer. But what I want is to be able to identify the name of the machine from where the database is created. For example the host name of creation.

I tried with

```
select * from sys.databases
```

but it doesn't I need.

Then I tried with

```
Select
database_name,server_Name,Machine_Name,b.[name]as Backup_Name,Backup_Start_Date,Backup_Finish_Date
,Physical_Device_Name
from  master.sys.databases a
Inner Join msdb..backupset
b             on
a.Name = b.Database_Name
Inner Join msdb..backupmediafamily
c     on    c.media_set_id
= b.media_set_id
WHERE database_name = 'database'
```

But I also do not get the data I need

Comment: Why negative feedback? No similar questions

Comment: I still do not understand why negative votes. No one gives solutions and does not even give explanations

Comment: Although I had not down voted you but the probable reason might be the lack of research before asking the question. I am a bit confused that, you want the name of the machine which created the database. But you should know that the database are always created by using someone's account. Hence, you have to first enable the audit to find out that as rightly pointed by @TheGameiswar

Comment: @geeksal First thanks for taking the time to give your opinion. Of course I did research, but if I detail it the post becomes very extensive. I go to the point. Because if it were the case that I did not do research, then what do you tell me about this post?

Http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255947/determine-what-user-created-objects-in-sql-server

What investigation was there? And so many votes in favor? How incoherent!

Comment: "[...] hit-and-run downvotes are, at best, pointless. Obviously you can’t expect everybody who votes down to leave a comment, particularly if there are already comments to explain existing down-votes; if the reason you think a post is bad has already been explained by someone else, repeating it is pointless. However if there are no comments or other down-votes, then a hit-and-run down-vote comes off as (and often is) just someone being petty or spiteful for some reason. Hiding their identity only makes it possible and easy to do this instead of making people accountable for their votes [...]"

Comment: SO is a continuously evolving site. The things which were in 2009 are no longer followed. We as a community has become mature, ethical and trying to follow best practices. However the 2009 post you pointed out If created now will be closed as off-topic as per rules. Also, remember these votes are cast by people like me and you. Hence there are bound to be differences. However, if you have some queries regarding SO policy you are free to raise a question on meta.

Comment: Assuming this is not a prod database, disable it and see who squeals. They'll probably be the creator or can tell you who it is. At the same time change your setup so that this is traceable from the beginning.

Comment: I understand your frustration. I personally think that people must comment before or after a down vote. However, the anonymity might be due to right to privacy of users (otherwise they will fear to raise their opinion), to avoid trolling and bullying. Finally, remember that in SO there are no personal issues among the users and SO ensures that nobody is victimized by following robust policy. I think you should read more about the site polices & working and  if you are still not satisfied raise question on meta and contribute to community development.

Comment: @DaveRlz It is an excellent strategy to disable the database and effectively is a development environment. And it turns out that we developers are in a development and testing environment so we have permissions to create databases. The problem is that a database appeared and apparently I am the suspect LOL, and although I was not who did it, I need something technical to prove that it was not me. And this will be very useful to DBAs in the future.

Comment: @geeksal I am totally grateful to the site and really my complaint is directly with users who vote negatively without leaving their reasons. I also understand that there are moderators and that they try to improve the SO. And about commenting on goal, of course it is very useful, although someone has already put the same "complaint" (I can not duplicate the same post) and I want to remind other users like me that the idea is to contribute in the best way. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: I was thinking, in proactive way, create a trigger in the master that gets the HOST_NAME when someone create a database ... I suppose after insert in sys.databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use extended events for this:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Create Database] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.database_created(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname)) 
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer;
GO
ALTER EVENT SESSION [Create Database] ON SERVER STATE = START;
```

I leave the consumption of the target data as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I will try this solution. And if I understand correctly, this would be a proactive solution and will help in the future. But to see databases created before that would not be possible, right?

Comment: Yes. To my knowledge, there's nothing that captures the information you're looking for by default, so this will only help for events that happen after the session is created.

Answer (score 0):

**To Get Host Name**

`SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName'

**To Get Machine Name**

`SELECT serverproperty('Machinename') as Hostname`

**Note:**

Host_Name means the sql server to which database is connected

Machinename means the machine name in which sql server is installed

Comment: I do not need the machine name of the current connection, but the name of the machine that created the database

Comment: Even machines or some service create database,they must be using some account which has permissions..you cant find that now ,unless you have audit enabled

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thanks for your reply. I know the name of the owner, which is the database creation account. But that is not the data I need but the name of the machine since the database was created.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Maybe the answer is "No, you can't" and describe how to Enable an audit before, as you say, because I do not know it.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I was thinking, in proactive way, create a trigger in the master that gets the HOST_NAME when someone create a database ... I suppose after insert in sys.databases